# 2019 Mustang Convertible rear window sticking

Tags: mustang, power-windows

Raising the rear windows with top closed, the driver side rear will stick. I can pull it up with my hand. General internet solution is to lubricate it, usually silicone lube recommended. The lube doesn't last, of course. Checking here for tips, such as if a dry lube might work (graphite, teflon) or if there is some easy adjustment. Although I'm not keen on opening up the inside panels.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the Mustang still within it's bumper-to-bumper warranty period? This seems like a problem which Ford should be solving. Do the windows *not stick* when the top is down?

Comment: Only sticks when top is up. I was hoping to avoid going to the dealer but as a 2019 it should still be within warranty.